# How to show/hide box on mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is the simplest way to do the following?

1. When user moves his mouse over the red box- the green box appears
2. If user moves his cursor from red to green box- the green box doesn't disappear
3. When user moves his cursor away from the green box (and not back to the red box)- the green box vanishes.

The red box doesn't touch the green box- like on the picture.

[image: Illustration]

Here's what I tried but that doesn't solve the problem:

```
$('#red').mouseenter(function()
{
    $('#green').show();
});
$('#green').mouseleave(function()
{
    $('#green').hide();
});
```

The problem here is that the green box vanishes once you move your cursor from red one.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: What's your html look like? Your javascript or css? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Some googling would probably lead you to a mouseenter and mouseleave example

Comment: @Jared I did a lot of Googling and didn't find a solution to this particular problem.

Comment: what does your html and css look like? also, in your example the red box never vanishes so `$('red').hide()` is likely incorrect...

Comment: How you have it currently works, since there is no hiding of the green box on the mouse leaving the `#red` box. http://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/mOVNGJ

Comment: @ChrisYongchu: Yes, it does. Seems I had to mess something up with my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to make this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <style media="screen">
        .red {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        .green {
            display: none;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: green;
        }
        .divider {
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".red").mouseenter(function(){
                $(".green").show();
            });
            $(".green").mouseleave(function(){
                $(".green").hide();
            });

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('.green').mouseenter(function () {...});` isn't necessary since it shows when the mouse already enters the red box. and if the green box is set to not display initially, a mouseenter on the green wouldn't work to display it.